# Set magento 2 layered navigation by clicking a custom button/link

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.9** website. I have created an **attribute** which is being used in **layered navigation** as well. So what I want is that when I click on a button on home page, this attribute should get selected automatically to a value.

For example : name of this attribute is Company and values are - google, stack-overflow, apple etc. so when I click on a **button/link** called "google" from homepage, then this attribute "company" should choose an option "google" in **layered navigation**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it by using the Id of attribute value, for example your attribute is Company and and value is google, then just check the Id of `google` from layer navigation and prepare url in home page like,

http://YOUR_BASE_URL/something.html?company=58

Where 58 is google Id and company is attribute code